# Query to update one table while joining another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table's column (table A, column = b_id) by inner joining another table (table B) matching their equal datetime (created_at) columns.

Table A

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id |     created_at      |  b_id | 
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2020-10-05 09:00:00 |  NULL |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  2 | 2020-10-05 09:05:00 |  NULL |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  3 | 2020-10-05 09:10:00 |  NULL |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |     created_at      |
+----+---------------------+
| 10 | 2020-10-05 09:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
| 11 | 2020-10-05 09:05:00 |
+----+---------------------+
| 12 | 2020-10-05 09:10:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

My following query works but i want to know if there is a more efficient way.

```
UPDATE A
INNER JOIN B ON A.created_at = B.created_at
SET A.b_id = B.id
WHERE A.created_at = B.created_at
```

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause. The condition is already there in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your update is fine, though you might want to add the following index to the `B` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_b ON B (created_at, id);  -- and drop id if you're using InnoDB
```

This would allow MySQL to do a rapid lookup in the `B` table using the `created_at` value, find the corresponding `id` value, assuming it exists.